# Why is a method ( getUser ) not being rendered?

Tags: reactjs, methods

The `getUser();` method call gives a pop up error in VsCode saying:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

the error is as follows:

> TypeError: users_list is undefined

I tried adding `{}` after the method, but it still gives the TypeError mentioned above.

any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
state = {
  users_id: [],
   error_message: ""
   };

async componentDidMount() {
try {
  const response = await fetch("//localhost:8080/users/list");
  const answer = await response.json();
  if (answer.success) {
    const users_list = answer.result;
    this.setState({ users_list });
  } else {
    const error_message = answer.message;
    this.setState({ error_message });
  }
} catch (err) {
  this.setState({ error_message: err.message });
}
}
   getUser();


  render() {
const { users_list, error_message } = this.state;

return users_list.map(user => (
  <div key={user.id}>
    {/* <p style={{ padding: "10px", margin: "50px" }}> */}
    <p>
      {user.id}, {user.name}, {user.email}, {user.password}, {user.phone}
    </p>
    {error_message ? <p> ERROR! {error_message}</p> : false}
  </div>
));
}

 }

export default App;
```

Comment: Format error message and highlight code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getUser is a function and can’t be declared without parentheses so

Change

```
  getUser();
```

To

```
 getUser(){

 }
```

And regarding below error you need to define/initialize users_list in state.

```
   TypeError: users_list is undefined
```

What happens is that users_list is not defined/initialized in state but setting users_list to state happening in componentDidMount so basically componentDidMount gets called after first render so on initial render users_list doesn’t exist in component state so you get that error. To fix the same

Change

```
  state = {
    users_id: [],
    error_message: ""
  };
```

To

```
 state = {
    users_id: [],
    error_message: "",
    users_list: [], //initialize with empty array
 };
```